# Align vertices of two objects after aligning the 2nd object to the normal of the 1st using python

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, normals, transform-orientation

I have an object "pl" that needs to be aligned on to the 2nd object "cube" such that the end vertices of both objects align with each other currently i aligned pl along the normal of the face of cube but i cannot get the end vertices aligned.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from bpy import context

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
pl = bpy.context.view_layer.objects["pl"]

obj_data =obj.data



for f in obj_data.polygons:
    c = f.center
    n = f.normal
    cpy=pl.copy()
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(cpy)
    rotation  = Vector((0,0,1)).rotation_difference(n)
    cpy.rotation_mode = "QUATERNION"
    cpy.rotation_quaternion = obj.matrix_world.to_quaternion() @ rotation
    
    cpy.location= c
```

[image]